# compiling opencv on alpine docker

Tags: java, opencv, docker, java-8, alpine-linux

I'm trying to compile opencv 2.4.9 from an Alpine base docker image.

I got it to compile, and my program is working but am seeing some warnings.
Wonder if I should be worried about this.

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/lib/libtbb.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will
>   try to fix the stack guard now.
>       It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.

Here's link to my Dockerfile
https://goo.gl/M1iuV9

Comment: did you resolve the issue?